# How to support user session to Vaadin project

Tags: spring, session, vaadin

I want to add user session support to my application. Since reloading the page will restart the application and even opening another browser tab will cause the original one 'out of sync' problem.

Do I need to create an independent window for each login, or is there any plugin I can use, or if I make it a Spring + Vaadin application, will it solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reloading the page should *not* restart the application, unless your url ends with `?restartApplication=true`.

The Application object is stored in the HTTP Session, therefore everything you want to store per user can be associated with the application.

Typically, each browser process can only support one HTTP Session, hence you will only be able to support one user per browser (unless you make significant efforts, and store per-user state on each application level Window. I recommend you don't do this unless you know what you are doing : one user-per-http-session is the norm in web applications)

Spring+Vaadin are a good combination - I am using this pairing to great effect in our projects - but are not particularly useful in this context.

Vaadin does not support multiple-windows/tabs in it's default configuration (hence your out-of-sync errors). However, it is trivial to write the code to do so : [here's a simple explanation, and some code](https://vaadin.com/web/joonas/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Supporting+Multible+Tabs)

Comment: @charlesmy problem is I added a closeListener to the window. which does ((WebApplicationContext)getContext()).getHttpSession().invalidate(); so that everytime reload the page, session expires. thanks

Answer (score 5):

Applications created with Vaadin Framework are automatically statefull, so your application should keep its state unless you have the ?restartApplication parameter in the URL.

To support multible browser tabs / windows in the same session, the getWindow(String name) must be overriden in the Application class to return a new Window instance for each browser tab / window:

```
@Override
public Window getWindow(String name) {

    // If the window is identified by name, we are good to go
    Window w = super.getWindow(name);

    // If not, we must create a new window for this new browser window/tab
    if (w == null) {
        w = new CalcWindow();

        // Use the random name given by the framework to identify this
        // window in future
        w.setName(name);
        addWindow(w);

        // Move to the url to remember the name in the future
        w.open(new ExternalResource(w.getURL()));
    }

    return w;
}
```

For more information about Vaadin's multi window support, see [this wiki page](https://vaadin.com/web/joonas/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Supporting+Multible+Tabs).

Comment: I used the method you provide. but I got error message Invalid security key received from 127.0.0.1? do you know why?

Comment: @henriI found the problem. I opened the same application within one browser, but different tabs, but if I open in two browsers. it has no problem. thanks.